# WPF Italic is not applying for Japanese font (In VS: 2010 Designer, OS: Windows7)

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

WPF Italic is not applying for Japanese font. Not even when i did in VisulaSudio 2010, it is not reflecting in Designer.

```
  <TextBox FontSize="50" FontStyle="Italic" >
       Text ﾃ｢竄ｬ窶             
  </TextBox>
```

[image: Italic is not applying for Japanese font]

Answer (score 0):

I got the Solution, if i specify MS FontFamily (ex: "MS Gothic", "MS Mincho"...). Its working fine, only these fonts supporting Italic for Japanes.

```
    <TextBox FontSize="40"
             FontFamily="MS Mincho"
             FontStyle="Italic" >
       Text ﾃ｢竄ｬ窶             
    </TextBox>
```